# MySQL: Calculating cumulative sum with nulls rows

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I calculate the cumulative sum of a column over time when many of the columns have null values?

I am trying the following, and my query times out with no specific error message:

```
SELECT t1.time_purchased, 
    t1.savings AS daily_savings,
    SUM(t2.savings) AS total_savings
FROM items AS t1, 
    items AS t2
WHERE t1.time_purchased >= t2.time_purchased
GROUP BY t1.time_purchased;
```

time_purchased and savings rows are often empty - is this causing the error?  If so, what can I do to skip these errors while still adding the savings to the total_savings?

Ideally, I would like to show the cumulative savings over time, independent of time_purchased. Thanks!

SOLUTION EDIT:

Thanks to everyone for there help.  The final solution required that my FROM statement select from a table in which savings had no null values, otherwise cumulative_sum continued to be null because I was adding a null value in some instances.  See the solution below:

```
SET @cumulative_sum := 0;
SELECT 
    time_purchased
    ,savings
    ,(@cumulative_sum := @cumulative_sum + savings) AS cumulative_sum
FROM (SELECT * FROM items WHERE savings IS NOT NULL) AS i
ORDER BY time_purchased;
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the null values. The problem is that the cross product is very large.

Comment: Does this table have savings for every customer? You're not grouping by customer, so this will have a row for every customer and every date, and it will show the cumulative sum for *all* other customers.

Comment: It does not have savings for every customer - how would you recommend I group by?

Comment: In that case you don't need to group it by customers. See the answer that Gordon Linoff posted for a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, the simplest way to do a cumulative sum is to use variables:

```
SELECT i.time_purchased,
       i.savings
       (@ds := @ds + i.savings) AS total_savings
FROM items i CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @ds := 0) params 
ORDER BY i.time_purchased;
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with the `NULL` values, but at least this should not time out.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response.  In the fourth line - "SUM(t2.savings) AS total_savings" - is there a typo?  I see you refer to t2.savings (when t2 doesn't exist here?) and alias the result as "total_savings" which has already been aliased on the previous line?  Also why is a select statement aliased as params but then params is never used?  Thank you for any further help you can provide!

Comment: Figured it out!  Thank you very much for your help :^)

Comment: @avtomate . . . That line was a typo